# Android SEND_SMS Permission Declare

Tags: android, flutter, sms, android-manifest, android-permissions

If your app requests to use sensitive permissions, such as SMS or Call Log permission groups, you must complete the Permissions declaration form.
I want to send sms to the user who added reference in my flutter application. I got send_sms permission for this, but play console does not allow it. It says that sms permission is among sensitive permissions and I do not use any of the options listed. How can I get sms permission

I changed the play console confidentiality agreement. I explained the function I made.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.